# MSTest ExpectedException failing

Tags: .net, exception, mstest

I usually use Nunit but in my current project I am using MSTest. Now I have a test which expects an exception but keeps failing, and I do not have any idea as to why.

Here is a simple example I have used to replicate the problem:

```
[TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(ErrorResponseException))]
        public void should_throw_exception()
        {
            throw new ErrorResponseException();
        }
```

The ErrorResponseException is a class that just inherits from Exception, that is it, anyone know why this is failing, I would expect it to pass.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In NUnit, I would avoid ExpectedException and use Assert.Throws (Exception Asserts) instead. It gives you finer-grained control. Otherwise the test will pass if any portion of the test method throws that exception.

In MSTest, you could get the same level of control with the old-school construct:

```
try
{
    // code that you expect to throw goes here
    Assert.Fail("Expected MyException");
}
catch (MyException ex)
{
    // optionally assert on the message - this can make tests fragile though
}
```

With this, there's no need for the ExpectedException attribute.

(The concept comes from the book Test-driven Development: A Practical Guide by David Astels.)

Comment: In my real scenario it is very similar to what you say to get it passing at the moment, I just found it odd that it doesn't work within MSTest. Will continue using this practise going forward then.

Comment: MSTest doesn't support this properly, its a bug. It is also super-lame! The workaround above will work however

Answer (score 5):

Shameless plug, but I wrote a simple assembly that makes asserting for exceptions and exception messages a little easier and more readable in MSTest using *Assert.Throws()* syntax. I wrote a [blog post](http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2012/01/asserting-exceptions-in-mstest-with.html) with the full details.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MSTest 10.0.1.0.0, ExpectedException doesn't seem to work correctly, use 10.0.0.0.0 instead.

Comment: True. I am facing this problem now.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same problem and found another solution. My method to test was `async` , but I forgot the `await` keyword infront of the call in my testmethod.

The Test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    public async Task ShouldDoSomething(){
         // notice the missing await in the next line
         this.testObject.DoSomethingAsync();
    }
```

The Method to test:

```
        public async Task<bool> DoSomethingAsync(){
            if(something)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Error while doing something");
            }
            return false;
        }
```

When I ran my test like this it failed. But as soon as I change the Test to the following:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
public async Task ShouldDoSomething(){
     await this.testObject.DoSomethingAsync();
}
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

In `Visual Studio 15`with dependencies on `MSTest.TestAdapter v1.1.18` and `MSTest.TestFramework v1.1.18` you could also use

`Assert.ThrowsException<ArgumentNullException>(() => MethodThatThrowsArgumentNullException());`

Answer (score 2):

The ExpectedExceptionAttribute is now defined in multiple DLLs and the unit test runner may be expecting to see the attribute from a different DLL to the one your test project is using.

As an example, I created a unit test project in VS2017 and it gets ExpectedException from Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework V14.0.0.0 - the test passes in the IDE but fails in TeamCity, even if using the VSTest runner on version 2017.

I eventually got it to pass in TeamCity by deleting all references to this DLL in my test projects and replacing them with version 10.0.0.0 of Mirosoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework